# Fetching data from database from ListView's onItemClickListener

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-listview

**SOLVED BELOW**

See below for solution

---

I have a `ListView` with a custom adapter which extends `CursorAdapter`. When the user clicks on an item in the `ListView` I want to open a new `Activity`(launched from the `openDigitalBusinessCardActivity` method), with the new `Activity` based upon the particular item in the `ListView` that was clicked. The new `Activity` needs the field `merchantID` from the database so I need to access this and then pass to the new `Activity` in my `Intent`.

However, I cannot get working how to access the correct data in my database based upon the feedback of the `ListView` click listener.

`Eclipse` gives me `Bad request for field slot` errors. My code for my listener is below:

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
          // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click registered!",
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

          //Cursor cur = (Cursor) adapter.getCursor();            
          //cur.moveToPosition(position);
          Cursor cur = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
          //Cursor cur = (Cursor)((MyCustomCursorAdapter) list.getAdapter().getItem(position));
          int merchantID = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("merchantID")); //Get the merchantID

          db.close();

         openDigitalBusinessCardActivity(merchantID);             
        }
      });
```

My database creation code is this:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
                "create table " + TABLE_SCORECARD + "(" 
                + COLUMN_MERCHANTID + " integer primary key, " 
                + COLUMN_MERCHANTNAME + " text not null, "
                + COLUMN_MERCHANTTAGLINE + " text not null, "
                + COLUMN_CURRENTSCORE + " Integer, "
                + COLUMN_FREEBIEPOINT + " Integer, "
                + COLUMN_CAMPAIGNID + " Integer, "
                + COLUMN_LISTPOSITION + " Integer);";
```

**---UPDATE---**

I have added an `_id` column to my table and now it looks like my query by the `_id` from `onItemClick` is not returning anything as my test on `cur.moveToFirst()` returns `false`. So `onItemClic`k is not returning a valid table row number.

```
list = getListView();

   list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
          // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click registered!",
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

          //Cursor cur = (Cursor) adapter.getCursor();            
          //cur.moveToPosition((int) id);
          //Cursor cur = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition((int) id);
          //Cursor cur = (Cursor)((MyCustomCursorAdapter) list.getAdapter().getItem(position));
          Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("select merchantID from scoreCard where _id = "+id,null);
          if(cur.moveToFirst()) {
              //int merchantID = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("merchantID")); //Get the merchantID
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cur.moveToFirst returned true",
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }           

          cur.close();
          db.close();

         // openDigitalBusinessCardActivity(merchantID);              
        }
      });
```

Comment: check merchantID datatype in your database is integer ?

Comment: It is. I access it using that exact same request in other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `Cursor` based adapters you get the `id` of the row in the `onItemClick` callback, is the `id` parameter. You should use that.

Comment: Unfortunately all that gave me was a new error "cursor index out of bounds exception"

Comment: @Roardog Where do you get that exception? The `id` parameter should be passed directly to `openDigitalBusinessCardActivity`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Why should I pass it directly to `openDigitalBusinessCardActivity`? That method needs the merchantID from the database so it can pass it to the activity it calls.

Comment: I don't have an _id field in my table, the merchantID field is set as the primarykey. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @Roardog I guess you figure it out?! If your `merchantId` column is created as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` and you pass it tot the list(along with the other column of the query) that will be the `id` parameter that is returned in the `onItemCLick` callback.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

Added _*id* field to my table and then passed the *long id* field provided by *onItemClick* to my method *openDigitalBusinessCardActivity(id);*. Passed *id* to the intent called by *openDigitalBusinessCardActivity(id);*. Then used *id* in the new activity to query the database.

My table:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
                "create table " + TABLE_SCORECARD + "(" + KEY_ROWID +" integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + COLUMN_MERCHANTID + " Integer, " 
                + COLUMN_MERCHANTNAME + " text not null, "
                + COLUMN_MERCHANTTAGLINE + " text not null, "
                + COLUMN_CURRENTSCORE + " Integer, "
                + COLUMN_FREEBIEPOINT + " Integer, "
                + COLUMN_CAMPAIGNID + " Integer, "
                + COLUMN_LISTPOSITION + " Integer);";
```

In my ListActivity:

```
list = getListView();

   list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Click ListItem Number " + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

        openDigitalBusinessCardActivity(id);
    }
   });
```